# PHP Mail() Failed to send email with attachment

Tags: php, zip, php-ziparchive

I'm attempting to create a zip of images, then send the email and attach the .zip file to the user. However, the email is not sending. I'm using mail() elsewhere on the server so I know the server isn't blocking this function.

```
if( (mysqli_num_rows($gallery_query) >= 1) || ($_SESSION['permission'] == 1) ){

        $photos = array();

        while( $photo = mysqli_fetch_assoc($gallery_query) ){

            $file_headers = @get_headers($photo[path]);
            if($file_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found' || $file_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 403 Not Found' || $file_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found' || $file_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden') {

                $file_headers = @get_headers($photo[image]); 
                if($file_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found' || $file_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 403 Not Found' || $file_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found' || $file_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden') {
                    //If we made it here we dont' have a copy of the image
                } else {
                    $photos[] = $photo[image];
                }
            } else {
                $photos[] = $photo[path];
            }   

        }

        //Begin zipping
        $zip = new ZipArchive();

        $tmp_file = tempnam('.','');
        $zip->open($tmp_file, ZipArchive::CREATE | ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE);

        foreach($photos as $file){
            try{
                    // download file
                    $download_file = file_get_contents($file);

                    //add it to the zip
                    $zip->addFromString(basename($file),$download_file);

            } catch(Exception $e){
            }

        }
        $zip->close();      

    } //End if mysqli_num_rows >= 1

    $htmlbody = " Your Mail Contant Here.... You can use html tags here...";
    $to = $email; //Recipient Email Address
    $subject = "Images"; //Email Subject

    $random_hash = md5(date('r', time()));

    $headers = "From: no-reply@DOMAIN.com\r\nReply-To: no-reply@DOMAIN.com";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n\r";
    $headers .= "\r\nContent-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"PHP-mixed-".$random_hash."\"";

    $attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($tmp_file))); 


    //define the body of the message.
    $message = "--PHP-mixed-$random_hash\r\n"."Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"PHP-alt-$random_hash\"\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= "--PHP-alt-$random_hash\r\n"."Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\r\n"."Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";


    //Insert the html message.
    $message .= $htmlbody;
    $message .="\r\n\r\n--PHP-alt-$random_hash--\r\n\r\n";


    //include attachment
    $message .= "--PHP-mixed-$random_hash\r\n"."Content-Type: application/zip; name=\"images.zip\"\r\n"."Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n"."Content-Disposition: attachment\r\n\r\n";

    $message .= $attachment;
    $message .= "/r/n--PHP-mixed-$random_hash--";


    //send the email
    $mail = mail( $to, $subject , $message, $headers );

    echo $mail ? "Mail sent" : "Mail failed";
```

Comment: `/r/n` that needs to read as `\r\n` - Then `$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n\r";` to `$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";` - the latter may not be as important, but you can try it.

Comment: I also noticed that you're using sessions. Make sure the session has been started if you haven't done so and not outputting before header. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your first opening `<?php` tag 
`<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); ?>` see if it yields anything.

Comment: haha it was that simple (/r/n to \r\n)... Thank you! I'll accept your answer as soon as stack overflow lets me.

Comment: You're welcome. It has been done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/r/n` that needs to read as `\r\n`

Then

```
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n\r";
```

to

```
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
```

the latter may not be as important, but you can try it to see if it helps.

- The `/r/n` is definitely a major issue though.